# Google Library Photos Api

Tags: java, android, google-photos, google-photos-api

```
 // Set up the Photos Library Client that interacts with the API
  PhotosLibrarySettings settings =
     PhotosLibrarySettings.newBuilder()
     .setCredentialsProvider(
         FixedCredentialsProvider.create(/* Add credentials here. 
 */)) 
    .build();

 try (PhotosLibraryClient photosLibraryClient =
    PhotosLibraryClient.initialize(settings)) {

    // Create a new Album  with at title
    Album createdAlbum = photosLibraryClient.createAlbum("My 
Album");

// Get some properties from the album, such as its ID and 
product URL
    String id = album.getId();
    String url = album.getProductUrl();

}    catch (ApiException e) {
    // Error during album creation
}
```

so my question is how to pass credentials on this parameter? (i want to use it on native android not web app or backend server ) im really struggling, got google sign in working though if i can use that to get credentials would be great :)

any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Create a UserCredetials Object

```
UserCredentials.newBuilder()
    .setClientId("your client id")
    .setClientSecret("your client secret")
    .setAccessToken("Access Token")
    .build()
```

and pass it to  `FixedCredentialsProvider.create())`

Take a look at this project to get full code 
https://github.com/erickogi/AndroidGooglePhotosApi/blob/master/app/src/main/java/ke/co/calista/googlephotos/Utils/PhotosLibraryClientFactory.kt

Comment: The problem is OAuth 2.0 Client with Android app doesn't have client secret. Did u have any suggestion for this problem ??